# Problems creating a message in teams from BotFramework Adapter

Tags: c#, azure, botframework, microsoft-teams

I'm using the FAQ PLUS Bot template.
I want to sent a post to a team channel. The message to publish in teams is created well, but when the code use 
`BotFrameworkAdapter.CreateConversationAsync()`, the execution fail because of a *bad request*. I've searched data about it but there isn't info related with it. I tested locally and in cloud but both fail.

The log output is:

> Microsoft.Bot.Schema.ErrorResponseException: Operation returned an invalid status code 'BadRequest'

The template is [this](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-faqplusplus-app) and the method that is failing it is found [here](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-faqplusplus-app/blob/70ce3e06e54cde63f3fbdc6577600164948587b4/Source/Microsoft.Teams.Apps.FAQPlusPlus/Bots/FaqPlusPlusBot.cs#L617).

The message that I want to send in an adaptive card, that I already validate

```
{
        "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
        "contentUrl": null,
        "content": {
          "type": "AdaptiveCard",
          "version": "1.0",
          "body": [
            {
              "type": "TextBlock",
              "size": "large",
              "weight": "bolder",
              "text": "Titulo",
              "wrap": true
            },
            {
              "type": "TextBlock",
              "text": "**** is requesting support.",
              "wrap": true
            },
            {
              "type": "FactSet",
              "facts": [
                {
                  "title": "Description:",
                  "value": "Descripcion"
                },
                {
                  "title": "Status: ",
                  "value": "Unassigned"
                }
              ]
            }
          ],
          "actions": [
            {
              "type": "Action.OpenUrl",
              "url": "https://www.google.com/search?q=RE%3A%20Titulo",
              "title": "Chat with "
            },
            {
              "type": "Action.ShowCard",
              "card": {
                "type": "AdaptiveCard",
                "version": "1.0",
                "body": [
                  {
                    "type": "Input.ChoiceSet",
                    "id": "Action",
                    "value": "AssignToSelf",
                    "style": "compact",
                    "isMultiSelect": false,
                    "choices": [
                      {
                        "title": "Assign to me",
                        "value": "AssignToSelf"
                      },
                      {
                        "title": "Close",
                        "value": "Close"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ],
                "actions": [
                  {
                    "type": "Action.Submit",
                    "data": {
                      "ticketId": "a3ac342f-b0e5-4ff4-855c-98856df7ed9b",
                      "action": null
                    }
                  }
                ]
              },
              "title": "Change status"
            }
          ]
        }
```

Let me know if any of you guys knows something about it.

Comment: @Micheal, I have tried the shared the adaptive JSON and it seems one closing curly brace "}" is missing at the end. Can you please try after adding it. If you still face the error, can you please share your bot id and timestamp of the error.

Comment: If that doesn't fix it, I'd recommend using one of the [official Bot Framework samples](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore). The Teams-related ones start are #s 50-60. I recommend looking at [#57](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/57.teams-conversation-bot) for proactive messaging.